# Initialise an array with same value, x times

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

If I have:

```
let a = [1,3,4,5];
```

how do I dynamically set `b` to have the same length as `a` with each entry containing "<", i.e.

Expected result:

```
b = ["<","<","<","<"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const a = [1,3,4,5];

const b = a.map(() => "<");

console.log(b);
```

You can use [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const a = [1,3,4,5];

const b = Array.from(a, () => "<");

console.log(b);
```

Or you can use [Array#fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```js
const a = [1,3,4,5];

const b = new Array(a.length).fill("<");

console.log(b);
```

Comment: I think my solution is clearer, what do you think? I think your map solution is much better than the array solution.

Comment: Ah. I see you've add an Array#fill solution as well :) Array#fill is good when you want to duplicate primitives. If you'll use an array or an object, all array items would point to the same array/object. Array#from/#map in this case are doing the same thing. I think I would go with map as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
Array(a.length).fill('<');
```